# How to share ActionName between webapi and client?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi

is there any way to share webapi ActionNames between client and api?
I tried something like this in:

```
public static class Orders
{
    public const string GetAllOrders = "GetOrders";
    public const string GetUserOrders = "GetUserOrders";
    public const string GetCustomerOrders = "GetCustomerOrders";
}
```

And then in api:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName(Orders.GetAllOrders)]
    public IActionResult GetAllOrders()
    {

        return BadRequest("No records found");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName(Orders.GetUserOrders)]
    public IActionResult GetUserOrders(int id)
    {
        return BadRequest("No records found");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName(Orders.GetCustomerOrders)]
    public IActionResult GetCustomerOrders(int id)
    {
        return BadRequest("No records found");
    }
```

But im getting this error:

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET api/Order" for actions - LPD_Api.Controllers.OrderController.GetAllOrders (LPD_Api),LPD_Api.Controllers.OrderController.GetUserOrders (LPD_Api),LPD_Api.Controllers.OrderController.GetCustomerOrders (LPD_Api). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround
```

Any tips how to share names to avoid naming errors on the client side?

Comment: Have you tried [HttpGet(Orders.GetCustomerOrders)] ?

Comment: Also you can get the name using nameof.
`public const string GetAllOrders = nameof(Controller.GetAllOrders);` 
In that case you will have up to date name even if someone renames method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to [Serhii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8978576/serhii) i resolved problem like this:

```
    [HttpGet(Orders.GetAllOrders)]
    public IActionResult GetAllOrders()
    {
        return BadRequest("No records found");
    }

    [HttpGet(Orders.GetUserOrders)]
    public IActionResult GetUserOrders(int id)
    {
        return BadRequest("No records found");
    }

    [HttpGet(Orders.GetCustomerOrders)]
    public IActionResult GetCustomerOrders(int id)
    {
        return BadRequest("No records found");
    }
```